# How to detect in after_commit callback that image (ActiveStorage::Attached::One) was changed to new one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to detect in `after_commit` callback that image (ActiveStorage::Attached::One) was changed to new one?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any callback in `ActiveStorage`.

The 2 workarounds I can suggest:

1. Comparing attachment `created_at` attribute, e.g. (Time.now - image.created_at) < 10, to know if it's newly created.
   Dirty, but gets the job done.
2. Wrap record creation in service object, where you can set a flag on the object if an attachment has changed.
   Something like this:

```
class UserUpdateService
   def call(attrs = {})
      attrs[:image_updated] = true if attrs[:image]
      User.update(attrs)
   end
end
```